# Attribute Error in Python

Tags: python, attributeerror

I'm trying to add a unittest attribute to an object in Python

```
class Boy:

    def run(self, args):
        print("Hello")

class BoyTest(unittest.TestCase)

    def test(self)
         self.assertEqual('2' , '2')

def self_test():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    suite.addTest(loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(Boy.BoyTest))
    return suite
```

However, I keep getting `"AttributeError: class Boy has no attribute 'BoyTest'"` whenever I call `self_test()`.  Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the argument of `loadTestsFromTestCase`, you're trying to access `Boy.BoyTest`, i.e., the `BoyTest` attribute of class object `Boy`, which just doesn't exist, as the error msg is telling you. Why don't you just use `BoyTest` there instead?

Answer (score -1):

As Alex has stated you are trying to use BoyTest as an attibute of Boy:

```
class Boy:

    def run(self, args):
        print("Hello")

class BoyTest(unittest.TestCase)

    def test(self)
         self.assertEqual('2' , '2')

def self_test():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    suite.addTest(loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(BoyTest))
    return suite
```

Note the change:

```
suite.addTest(loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(Boy.BoyTest))
```

to:

```
suite.addTest(loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(BoyTest))
```

Does this solve your problem?